# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects' when using count and sum

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with show total number of my list. I want to count the total number of my list_value variable below, but it seems it returning an error.

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects' when using count
```

> views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='log_permission')
def data_table(request):
   if request.method=='POST':

    province = request.POST['province']
    municipality = request.POST['municipality']

    list_value = 
    Person.objects.filter(province=province,municipality=municipality)
    final_value = list_value.objects.count()  //here is the problem
    total =dats.objects.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
    print(final_value)
    print(total)
    return render(request, 'data_table.html')
```

> models

```
class Person(models.Model):
   covid_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   middle = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
   lastname   = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
   extension  = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
   province  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   municipality  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   barangay = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   remarks = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   amount = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   remarks_miray = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   count = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the **`object`**, just call **`count()`** method

```
count_value = list_value.count()
```

Comment: How about the sum? I used  variable_name.aggregate(Sum('amount'))  but it returns output like this {'amount__sum': 167200.0} . I just want the variable 167200.0

Comment: Use **`get()`** method as `variable_name.aggregate(Sum('amount')).get("amount__sum")`

Answer (score 0):

list_value is already a QuerySet and not a Django model. therefore .objects is unavailable. you can just iterate through list_value.
more info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects